# How do you create an array from the fields from a database resultset in Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Basically I have 3 fields in the database table and I want to return a an array to represent each row.

sqlite database resultset:

```
row 1)
name: John
gender: male
email: john@john.com

row 2)
name: Sarah
gender: female
email: sarah@sarah.com
```

Desired format from the above resultset:

```
[['John',male,'john@john.com'],['Sarah',female,'sarah@sarah.com']]
```

I've tried using `User.all.map(&:name)` but that only gives me `['John','Sarah']`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll want to use `map`, but like this:

```
User.all.map {|u| [u.name, u.gender, u.email]}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
User.all.map {|u| [u.name, u.gender, u.email] }
```